# How can I get the data from USB port in flutter windows app

Tags: windows, flutter, usb, port, flutter-dependencies

Currently, I am working on a Flutter Windows app and need to add a new feature that allows me to receive data from a USB port. The expected data will be in a continuous format through the device. As this is my first time working on a Windows app, I am unsure of how to implement this feature. Any ideas?